# Ruby: axlsx : How do I bold and change BG color for selected cells?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I'm using the axlsx ruby gem to create an Excel file and I can't figure out how to apply bold and background style only to the selected cells (here State Cells)

I went thru methods like col_style and row_style and add_conditional_formatting but couldn't exactly sort out, how to use it in my code or whether it is really of any help to my requirement here.

Current Data structure:

```
work = [ {:state=>"Texas", :details=>{}}
{:city=>"LasVegas", :details=>{"Rob"=>"Doctor", "Dino"=>"Artist"}}
{:city=>"El paso", :details=>{"Jer"=>"Journalist", "Milo"=>"Vet"}}

{:state=>"Florida", :details=>{}}
{:city=>"Miami", :details=>{"Jake"=>"Army", "Steve"=>"Retired"}}
{:city=>"Tampa", :details=>{"Cohen"=>"Teacher", "Mike"=>""}} ]
```

My Code snippet:

Only the Excel part

```
require 'axlsx'
p = Axlsx::Package.new

p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "Data") do |sheet|
    style1 = sheet.styles.add_style(:bg_color => "EF0920", :fg_color => "FFFFFF", b:true)
    style2 = sheet.styles.add_style(:bg_color => "00FF00", :fg_color => "FFFFFF", b:true)
    sheet.add_row ["State", "City", "Name", "Profession"], :style => style1
    work.each do |val|
      sheet.add_row [ val[:state], val[:city] ]
      val[:details].each do |k, v|
        sheet << ["", "",  k, v]        
      end 
     end
    sheet.add_row
end

p.serialize 'Data.xlsx
```

1. I've tried to add an empty line between every `state` using `sheet.add_row` but it's not working. (for legibility)
2. Wanted to bold and apply background of gree only to the state's cells
3. lastly a format mismatch.

I hope I've conveyed my problem clearly and thanks in advance for any help

**Current Format**

[image: CUrrent output]

**Expected Format**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The style method takes an array for each cell so if you do the following you will have a bold "State" field with the other cells in the row lacking styles unless added specifically:

```
embolden_style = style.add_style(b: true,bg_color: '78F2FF')
sheet.add_row ["State", "City", "Name", "Profession"], style: [embolden_style, nil, nil, nil]
```